# Python - Text from a file won't be printed

Tags: python-3.x

I'm attempting to create a quiz program that reads questions from one file, whilst reading the correct answers from another file. At the moment my program will not print out the questions or the answers, offering no error message either, leaving me rather confused...
Please excuse my newbie code as I'd really appreciate any help! :)

```
def quiz():
 score = 0
 time.sleep(1)
 topic = input ("Please choose the topic for the quiz. The topics available are: \n- Computer Science \n- History \n Please enter in lower case.\n - ")
 difficulty = input("Please choose the diffilculty. The difficulties available are: \n- Easy \n- Hard \n- ")

  i = 0
  for i in range(0,4):
    with open(topic+" "+difficulty+".txt", "r") as questions:
        question = questions.readline(i)
    print(question)
    time.sleep(0.9)
    #questions.close
    with open (topic+" "+difficulty+" answers.txt", "r") as answers:
        answer = answers.readline(i)
    print(answer)
    #answers.close
    userAns = input()
    #questions.close
    #answers.close
    i = i + 1
    if userAns == answer:
        score = score + 1
return score
```

Comment: `questions.readline(i)` - what is the `i` for? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: do you call the quiz function later in the file?

Comment: When opening a file its internal "filepositionpointer" is at 0 - every time. If you want to read multiple lines use `.read().split('\n')` or '.readlines()' - if you read a single line use `.readline()`. Read the whole file, put it into a list and work from there, do not mix reading and intput and printing and sleeping in one block.

Comment: I must be incredibly dumb... (doh) Removing the i makes the first question print out every time, how do I make it move on to the next line so the next question and answer can be read/printed?

Comment: Indent ``print(function)`` so it's inside the loop